# Fill in the gaps from a ST_Union of multiple polygons

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql, union

I have the following polygons:

```
01060000000300000001, 01060000000400000001, 01060000000400000001, 01060000000200000001, 01060000000100000001, 01060000000200000001, 01060000000100000001, 01060000000300000001, 01060000000100000001, 01060000000100000001, 01060000000100000001, 01060000000100000001
```

And I'd like to merge them using:

```
SELECT st_union(ARRAY(SELECT geom FROM areas))
```

And I get: `https://pastebin.com/V18JtCz8` (I should paste here but it's above the char count - if you're reading this and the link doesn't work, it's simply the output of the above)

When I plot this output, there are holes (deliberate) but I'd like to just take the outline of the polygon as the new polygon.

How would I go about this?

Comment: External links are unlikely to be followed (and likely to  fail over time). Instead, include a screenshot of a map.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, simply call ST_ExteriorRing on the geom to create the outline and then create a polygon from that.

So `SELECT ST_MakePolygon(ST_ExteriorRing(st_union(ARRAY(SELECT geom FROM areas))))`

This will fill in all the gaps.

Read more here: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html and here: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html